# PHP Script to identify if given file name string or url string is of valid video mimetype

Tags: php, video

Is it possible and how to determine if the given string of filename or url is a valid resource for video? I have a project which fetches data from rss feed and only filter videos. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `curl_getinfo()`:

```
<?php
// get file headers
$ch = curl_init('http://www.test.com/data.avi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);

// get content type
$allowed_content_types = array("video/x-msvideo", "video/mp4");
$content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
if (in_array($content_type, $allowed_content_types) {
    // your code here
}
```

It allows you to get accurate MIME type of file and check if it's the one you need.
If you just want to check file extensions - you can `explode` url string by dot, get latest element and  use `in_array` to check if it is in array of allowed extensions:

```
$url = "http://test.com/data.avi";
$extension = pathinfo("test.s.d", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$allowed_extensions = array("avi", "mp4");
if (in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) here

```
$url = 'http://example.com?index.php&file=mp4';

if (strpos($url,'mp4')) {
  echo 'true';
}
```